# How do I use Dagger?

Tags: java, eclipse, dagger

I've recently heard of the concept of Dependency Injection so I decided to learn about it. So, this is very stupid, rookie quesiton, and I tried hard to find some clues around the web not to ask it but I've given up:

*How do I use Dagger?*

I downloaded the JARs, added them to the Java project (which is basically the [coffee example](https://github.com/square/dagger/tree/master/examples/simple/src/main/java/coffee)) with *Add External JARs...* (I'm using Eclipse). Got some compiler errors about missing library `javax.inject` but I managed to find it somewhere and added it aswell. Also removed some `@Override` tags because the compiler didn't like them.

Now I'm getting this thing in the console

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module adapter for class coffee.DripCoffeeModule could not be loaded. Please ensure that code generation was run for this module.
```

and I have no idea what that means.

I only want to see some working code but I barely know what I'm doing. Help please.

**EDIT:**

also I've been seeing stuff like

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.+'
    provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.+'
}
```

(for example [here](http://antonioleiva.com/dagger-android-part-2/)) but with no explanation whatsoever. What do I do with that?

Comment: @Override has nothing to do with Dagger. But I'm also interested, as I want to use it and tbh tutorial on Dagger's site misses few things.

Comment: @spoko
Well, I know what's up with `@Override` but the coffee example has those tags at every method which is strange since there's nothing to override.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There several blog posts on installing dagger on eclipse without maven.  Here is the one that I used (I think)

http://www.thekeyconsultant.com/2013/09/adding-dagger-to-your-android-project.html

but here is another.

http://scouse.com/adding-dagger-to-an-android-eclipse-project/

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for something *exactly* like this but somehow I couldn't find it.